# Is Adobe the only company that can license usage of Myriad Pro?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, font-licensing

I am trying to get Myriad Pro onto my website and I have the use of Adobe's Typekit, but I think that it is stuck in the last decade with its JS loading and FOUT so I am wanting to embed the fonts using `@font-face`.

Is Adobe the only company that licenses the use of Myriad Pro, as they won't give us a server license to use the fonts in this way, or am I able to obtain a license from elsewhere?

The company already has a license that allows it to use the font in all the commercial brochures and prints, but I'm not sure if this covers us for using it on the web.

Any advice about this would be much appreciated as I am getting nowhere asking the marketing department who are adamant I must use the font on the website.

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: @ZachSaucier Hi, is this question not on topic for this site?  I did check the guidelines and felt it came under the topic: *Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication* and as there is a tag for `font-licensing` I guess this should be ok?

Comment: To me it seems on topic

Comment: http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/myriad looks like they have it as part of a subscription service too maybe? I don't see much else apart from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe owns Myriad...it's a typeface they commissioned for their own foundry. Adobe also owns Typekit. They want you to use typekit to license Myriad for the web.

Answer (score 4):

Adobe recently shut down their type store and send most of their licensing queries for [Myriad Pro](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/myriad-pro) to us at fontspring.com. That said, Adobe only allows us at this time to sell desktop licenses, because Typekit is their web font product. They do not want their commercial fonts used as web fonts in a self-hosted manner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reminds me of how the Adobe font itself is only usable by Adobe.